# Should I duplicate the form validation on client side in server side just like client side validations?

Tags: javascript, php, validation, security, user-experience

A person can come and create an account.
I've implemented a great validation on client side, for example if he does not provide a valid email address, I will inform him right away that is is not valid email (with client-side JavaScript).

But client-side validation can be easily bypassed by an attacker. So I have also used the same validation on server side as well. But the difference is user experience. For example, if JavaScript on the client side is disabled and the user provides a invalid email, the application will just tell him error (after the form is submitted and page refreshed). No more information. (because I assume he is an attacker so my website should have awful user experience for an attacker).

Now my question is this: Will be my website's user experience be okay if I do that? (Great error reporting to users on the client side but awful on server side, server side will just return 'error' after the whole form submitted for any failed validation).

**More Explanation:**

Whenever a user types invalid text into inputs, the application will tell him right at the bottom of the input with red text that he has not typed valid text. (This will happen because of client-side JavaScript).

But if somehow client-side JavaScript has been disabled and a user types invalid text into a input, server side will return just 'error' to the user after page submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already doing the server-side validation, the question really is whether you want to still provide a comparable user experience for users who don't get the client-side validation for whatever reason, and that's up to you.

I don't think it's 100% safe to assume that *everyone* with JavaScript disabled is up to no good, but the percentage of legit users without JavaScript is probably small enough that you don't need to invest in providing the same level of  user experience for them. [This Q&A on ux.stackexchange.com](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/45229/should-i-optimize-my-website-for-non-javascript-users) may offer some insight on that. (It's a bit old, but I think its points are still valid.)

A reasonable compromise might be to add a [`<noscript>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript) tag in your generic error with a message to inform them that they won't see detailed errors with JS disabled.

Answer (score 8):

*Never* rely on client side validation. It can be easily bypassed. *Always* validate on the server side. The client side validation is  a nice to have as it gives immediate feedback which makes for a better user-experience. But the only validation you can rely on is one that cannot be subverted by the user which means it must reside on the server (or anywhere not in the client's browser/device).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I've done. But should server side return good information on where the problem was? or just a message like 'error' will be fine on every failed form validation? Because I assume he is an attacker so the worse user experience the better. Please read More Explanation.

Comment: IMO if the user is subverting your client side validation I don't care at all if they get nice messages, because they are trying to break in anyway.

Comment: So just hackers and malicious user will disable javascript on client side? Do normal user disable that so I need a high user experience error reporting system on server side as will just in case client javascript was disabled?

Comment: Always assume your users are simultaneously malicious *and* stupid. Try to be helpful, but don't give them anything that will help defeat your system.